Selection of nq1, nq2 and nq3
I want to calculate Tc. For this I have made scf.in, ph.in, nscf.in and epw.in sequentially.
But i am not clear how to select nq1, nq2 and nq3 for &inputph i.e for ph.x. Give me detail for this for different crystal structure.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In my experience, nq1, nq2, and nq3 are divisors of kpoints (kx, ky, kz) specified in the scf.in file.
